# indesign javascript to get the selected glyph ID, not the contents

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Is it possible to get the value (contents) of an actual glyph, not its typed value in InDesign?

Example:

This is what is typed in InDesign:

Ελλάδα

Then uppercase style is applied to it to make it look like that:

ΕΛΛΑΔΑ

Notice how the first accented ά changed into Α (no accent).
When accessing this letter with javascript, one still gets ά:

```
app.selection[0].contents.charAt(0)
```

I need to get the actual glyph that is displayed - Α.
Is there a way to do that with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply command `Type` > `Change Case` > `UPPER CASE`:

[image]

It gets the desired result:

[image]

First line is an original, second line -- uppercase style, third line -- uppercase conversion.

If you need to do it via script an implementation depends on your workflow.

Comment: Thanks. Try retrieving the second line in your screenshot with javascript and you would still get Ελλάδα. I need it to return ΕΛΛΑΔΑ. toUpperCase() returns ΕΛΛΆΔΑ. Scripting to search/replace is a solution but I wonder if there is a way to retrieve the displayed text directly. The Glyphs panel shows the correct character - Α, so it should be possible. Or not..?

Comment: Yeah. Something like `getDisplayValue()`. It would be great. But I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Ideally it would be possible to get the GID or CID of a character, the rest is easy.

Comment: Factually I can get the GID by invoking the menuAction to insert selection into Find Glyph  panel and then read the glyphId value. But for the life of me I don't know how to convert GID into Unicode.

Comment: Wow. Frankly, I don't even sure if I understand what the GID is, and what is it for. Something about the dark Unicode magic, I suppose. )

Answer (score 0):

It seems I did not quite understand the question. You want to get `A` from `ά` for all accented Greek letters in upper case.

Probably you need to do such conversation by your self.  Something like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var accented     = 'άέήίόύώ';
var not_accented = 'αεηιουω';

// find only for caps
app.findGrepPreferences.capitalization = Capitalization.ALL_CAPS;

// change all accented upper cased letters with no_accented ones
for (var i=0; i<accented.length; i++) {
    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat   = accented[i];;
    app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = not_accented[i];
    doc.changeGrep();
}

// restore find prefs
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
```

Beware, the operation `Ά` --> `A` is irreversible. You can't get `ά` back from the plain `A`.

If you want to change selected text only you can do it this way:

```
var sel = app.selection;
if (sel[0].constructor.name != 'Character') var sel = sel[0].characters;

var accented     = 'άέήίόύώ';
var not_accented = 'αεηιουω';

for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    if (sel[i].capitalization != Capitalization.ALL_CAPS) continue;
    var index = accented.indexOf(sel[i].contents);
    if (index > -1) sel[i].contents = not_accented[index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The workflow is the javascript. I know how to do the case conversion with InDesign interface and "irreversible" conversion is out of question. Your javascript snippet is somewhat similar to what I ended up writing for now. I don't use findGrep() command - I parse the text directly by Story. I then "recompile" all text as a string with all-capped text converted using similar loop to yours. So far it works, but I wish there was a way to simply retrieve the displayed text as it is, not its underlying value.